# Declaration after use

Tags: c++, standards, name-lookup

The draft C++20 standard [N4861](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/n4861.pdf) sect. 6.5.1(7) reads:

> A name used in the definition of a class `X` outside of a
> complete-class context of `X` shall be declared ... before its use in
> class `X` or be a member of a base class of `X`....

So why does the following compile?

```
#include <iostream>
  
struct X {
    X(const int i_) : i(i_) {}
    int f() const { return 3*g(); }
    int g() const { return 2*i; }
    const int i;
};

int main()
{
    const X x{7};
    std::cout << x.f() << "\n";
}
```

I mean, of course, it should indeed compile, and does, and the output is `42` just as one would expect; but I do not understand the standard's phrasing. The standard says, "before its use," but in the example, isn't `g()` declared *after* its use? And `i`, too.

Comment: Your example doesn't break the rule you're citing.

Comment: @sweenish Yes, thanks, I am sure that you are right; but I don't understand the phrasing. Would you like to explain?

Comment: `struct X { ... };` is a complete-class context

Comment: To my understanding, the key part is "outside of a complete-class context." I see that you use `g()` in `f()`, and `g()` had not formally been declared yet, but it's in the class `X`. If `g()` were a global function declared and implemented *after* `X`, I think that's where you'd run into an issue. If clas `X` had a member `Y` object, the compiler needs to know all about Y first so that it can be included. That's what the rule is saying.

Comment: @RichardCritten Aha. Apparently, the standard's use of the adjective "complete" has confused me. If you'd like to make your comment an *answer,* I'd be glad to upvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key part to the paragraph you are quoting is

> outside of a complete-class context

Inside a member function body, you are in a complete-class context.  This means the rule does not apply.

The full definition for a complete-class contect can be found in [[class.mem.general]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#mem.general-7):

> A complete-class context of a class (template) is a
>
> - function body ([dcl.fct.def.general]),
> - default argument ([dcl.fct.default]),
> - default template argument ([temp.param]),
>   noexcept-specifier ([except.spec]), or
> - default member initializer

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you're not breaking the rule cited.

To my understanding, the key part is "outside of a complete-class context." I see that you use `g()` in `f()`, and `g()` had not formally been declared yet, but it's in the class `X`. If `g()` were a global function declared and implemented after `X`, I think that's where you'd run into an issue. If class `X` had a member `Y` object, the compiler needs to know all about `Y` first so that it can be included. That's what the rule is saying.

Comment: Misread the comment. I'll leave it to Richard to post an answer.

Comment: Kindly leave your answer. Don't remove. It's helpful.